# Freestyle depth of field

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle, depth-of-field

I am using Freestyle on a Cycles scene with some depth of field. The Freestyle doesn't get affected by the depth of field, and so pops out too much on objects that aren't in focus. I am looking for any sort of trick or method to get some blur on that FS without also blurring it on the focus.

I could switch to doing fake DoF on the whole scene in post processing, but are there any other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, it looks like the best option is similar to what squarespiral suggested, but instead use Distance from Object, and place the object (likely an empty) at the focal point of the shot. Then use distance from object to add thickness, alpha, etc.

Comment: I have the same Problem! Can you post some photos of demonstrating it so it & Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Freestyle is applied after the actual render, so the short answer is: no, you have to work with post processing (maybe filtering the freestyle edges with a Kirsch filter and apply the blur only to that portion of the image).

But, you might be able to fake something using the "Distance from camera" modifiers in freestyle. This modifier can be applied to color, alpha and thickness. The settings are under line style - here is a quick example:

[image: Freestyle edges with distance from camera modifiers applied to line color thickness and alpha]